# Wordpress meta_query >= & <= operator only retrieving posts equal to numeric value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have WordPress query arguments that need to filter posts based on two meta key's values based on if the two values are >= and <= to two numbers.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'vacancy',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$vacancy_small_salary = 3000; //these are dynamically inputted from $_POST
$vacancy_large_salary = 5000; //these are dynamically inputted from $_POST

//append search queries to arguments
if ( !is_null($vacancy_small_salary) && !is_null($vacancy_large_salary) )
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'  => 'vacancy_small_salary',
            'value' => $vacancy_small_salary,
            'operator'  => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key'  => 'vacancy_large_salary',
            'value' => $vacancy_large_salary,
            'operator'  => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
);
```

The problem I'm getting is that it won't find posts that have a $vacancy_small_salary greater than the inputted var, and $vacnacy_large_salary smaller than it's inputted var.

It does however find posts when the two values **equal** each other (i.e. if a post has 3000 as the small salary and 5000 as the large salary.)

Could it be that my logic is wrong with the way it manages >= and <=, or maybe the values aren't truly numeric so it cannot search properly? <- I suspect this is not the case, but it's been racking my head for a while now.

As always if you require any more information please ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the solution.

I needed to use **compare** instead of **operator** in the meta_query

so

```
array(
  'key'  => 'vacancy_small_salary',
  'value' => $vacancy_small_salary,
  'operator'  => '>=',
  'type' => 'NUMERIC'
),
```

becomes

```
    array(
      'key'  => 'vacancy_small_salary',
      'value' => $vacancy_small_salary,
      'compare'  => '>=',
      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
```

and the same for the other query